# python - how to check if an IP address belongs to a list of IP subnets

Tags: python, python-2.7

Which is the faster way to check if an IP address is belonging to a list of IP subnets?

Let's say that we have the following IP subnets list:

```
ip_ranges =     [
    '192.168.12.0/19',
    '209.102.103.0/20',
    '104.105.106.0/24'
                ]
```

and now I want to check if the IP `209.102.103.0` belong to the `ip_ranges` list.

I have tried the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import socket
import sys
from netaddr import *
from ipaddress import ip_network, ip_address

fun check_ip(ip):
    ip_ranges =     [
        '192.168.12.0/19',
        '209.102.103.0/20',
        '104.105.106.0/24'
                    ]

    networks = [ip_network(range) for range in ip_ranges]

    for n in networks:
        if ip_address(ip) in n:
            print("Yes")



domain = "google.com"
ip = socket.gethostbyname(domain)
check_ip(ip)
```

Unfortunately, always I am getting the following exception error.

`ipaddress.AddressValueError: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address. Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode object?`

Any idea what is the problem there?

Comment: Do not blindly except *everything*. This way you do not know what the *actual* error is – and neither do we. Remove the `try..except` and add the full traceback. It will help us help you.

Comment: @usr2564301 Yep, you are right! I have edited my post! I am getting `Unexpected error: <class 'ipaddress.AddressValueError'>
` Cheers!

Comment: "The full traceback" includes more useful information, such as the exact line that caused the error.

Comment: @usr2564301 Here you go: `'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address. Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode object?`

Comment: Actual error after editing the code: ipaddress.AddressValueError: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address. Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode object?

Comment: First you need to do is remove either [tag:python-2.7] or [tag:python-3.x] from your question. An answer may depend on this. Surely you are aware which version you are using? Or do you *need* a solution that works on both?

Comment: @usr2564301 I am using Python 2.7.17. No I need solution that works only in my version. I'll remove python-3.x Thank you!

Comment: The above code actually is a function and I am sending the IP address to that function for the check...

Comment: @usr2564301 I have added my full code if that help to understand better what is going wrong...